# How to create plugin for mpg in a digital library using perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am looking for creating a plugin for greenstone digital library for extracting metadata from mpg file.Can anyone help me with any documentation?I am totally new in perl,so I am also looking for good reference book for learning perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Image::ExifTool`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image%3a%3aExifTool) can be used for parsing MPEG (and many other formats) files. The documentation has many usage examples. For example, to print the `BitDepth` of a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::ExifTool;

my $filename = '/path/to/file';

my $exif_tool = Image::ExifTool->new;
$exif_tool->ExtractInfo($filename);
print $exif_tool->GetValue('BitDepth');
```